# State management in React component when the business logic is outside of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

there! The App component is a container for three different components:

- `Map` renders a map with visual marks on it representing addresses the user has provide.
- `List` component contains all added addresses as list items.
- `Input` allows a user to add a new address (in my terms that is called *LocationPoint*).

Right now, the `App` keeps `locations` array in state with all those addresses (*LocationPoints*) and passes that array into all child components.

Manipulations with LocationPoints (add/move/update/deleteLocationPoint) are taken out to separate function as they are quite generic and may be reused somewhere else later.

But because those functions do not know about state existence I have to create some kind of "provider" functions that calls those actions (addLocationPoint, deleteLocationPoint, etc). E.g. `addLocationPoint` func has to be called inside `App.addLocationPoint`.

The following example should explain what I was talking about better. Note: snippet doesn't work as it's not a real implementation.

```js
// Adds a new location point
const addLocactionPoint = (locations: array, address: string) => {
  // ...
  return updatedLocations;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      locations: [],
    }

    // bind addLocPoint, etc.
  }

  addLocPoint(address) {
    this.setState(state => {
      addLocactionPoint(state.locations, address);
    });
  }

  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <Input onSubmit={ this.addLocPoint } />
      <List 
        onDrag={ this.moveLocPoint }
        onDelete={ this.deleteLocPoint } 
      />
      <Map data={ this.state.locations } />
    );
  }
}
```

Can my approach be considered as a good practice? Or there are other ways to reduce amount of logic in App component and to avoid creating those "providers" without using state management libs (MobX, Redux, etc). Maybe the case I consider is a right time to introduce a Redux or MobX?

I'll be really grateful for advice or recommendations or links to explore on this question.

Comment: *Maybe the case I consider is a right time to introduce a Redux or MobX?* - seems like that. Not necessarily one of them. There's a bunch of smaller state management libs that may suit your needs.

Comment: @estus Thanks, I feel the same deep inside me. 
Right now, I'm trying to figure out whether the practice I've been using is acceptable first (or there are some painful cons of it that will hit me later) and are there any options to improve it so I can avoid those providers. 
The most interesting thing is whether or not I can be achived with no extra library.

Comment: Separating business logic from components is considered one of major selling points of Redux. You may take a look at Redux Saga or Redux Logic, that's where the idea becomes obvious. With no extra library, it seems to be pretty good as it is. If you need to manage state in nested components, you may additionally use context API to pass global scope to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already good enough, this is how global state is usually maintained in vanilla React with no state management libraries. Context API may additionally be used to pass the state to nested components.

The thing that can be changed is that functions that update the state can actually be extracted and used as `setState` *higher-order* updater functions:

```
const addLocationPoint = (address) => ({ location }) => {
  // ...
  return updatedLocations;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  addLocPoint(address) {
    this.setState(addLocationPoint(address));
  }
  ...
```

A similar idea is used in Redux action creators.

In order for state updaters to provide real improvements, they have to be moved to another module. In this case they can be tested separately from a component that uses them and mocked with `jest.mock` in a component that uses them.

Comment: I haven't touched the Redux so the concept of updater functions is unfamiliar to me, I already like the style. I'm going to update those *LocationPoint functions in this way. 
And the note about mocking them in a component sounds useful to me.
Thanks for your guidance!

The Context API is probably not a good much in my case just because I don't have a deep tree of components. But I'm sure that I was wrong when I've missed the advanced section of the React Docs, I'll definitely catch up with that.